# I need to get the list of all the windows displayed or hidden in the desktop

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib

I'm trying to code something using X11 related libraries such as `Xlib` and `Xrandr`.

At first I was expecting a full coverage of the real basic functions such as retrieving the refresh rate from the monitors from `Xlib` alone, later on I find out that I need `Xrandr` for that.

Now I need to get the list of all the windows displayed or hidden in the desktop, I'm not thinking about using Gnome/KDE/XFCE ... extensions because I know that those are just decorators for X11, but I can't really find a function or a macro that is able to enumerate the open windows in the X server.
I also need to get the ID/name of the window that is under focus.

My question is: `Xlib` alone is capable of doing this ? Because from the terminology that Xlib adopts, I have my doubts that this functions could possibly even exist.

Comment: by the way I managed to get the input and not the focus ( in terms of windows ), I know how to get the coordinates of the cursor but without the informations on the windows it's useless.

Comment: @n.m. question: it's better to use the DRI libs ? i noticed that xlib it's not the latest and greatest while using it, it lacks many features.

Comment: What DRI libs? Cairo? It goes on top of Xlib, not instead of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of child windows with `XQueryTree`

```
XQueryTree - query window tree information

Status XQueryTree(Display *display, Window w, Window *root_return, Window *parent_return, Window **children_return, unsigned int *nchildren_return);
```

So, to get a complete list, you'll have to start with the root window and recursively call it for all the children of each window.

Comment: ok, I'll try that as soon as possible, but what about the user focus ?

Comment: Sorry, been away - XGetInputFocus as n.m. said